# How can I convert a periodically changing div in a react app to a gif format

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, gif, animated-gif

I have a div in my react application that changes colour every second. How can I record just this div element for 5 seconds and save it as a gif:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const DivColorChange = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setColor((prevColor) => (prevColor === "red" ? "blue" : "red"));
    }, 1000); // Change color every 1 second

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  const divStyle = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px",
    backgroundColor: color,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  };

  return <div style={divStyle}></div>;
};

export default DivColorChange;
```

I am stuck here and cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried to make a screenshot / gif animation with javascript? There are libraries that do those things, did you google for them?